# Return rows that meet a condition in two different columns

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table describing the color and smell of an animal. I am trying to filter it to see what animals are the same color and smell. I do not care if multiple animals use the same color or use the same smell, but if they use the same color AND smell, that is what I want to see.

I have tried using `union` and also and `select` statement with `in` after a `where`. I think I understand how to compare multiple columns if they are in different tables, but I can't seem to do it if the columns are in the same table.

Table: Animals

```
Name| color| smell
-------------------------
cat | red  | bad
dog | red  | bad 
rat | red  | good
bat | red  | decent
bee | red  | okay
ape | red  | okay
ant | red  | bad
```

I want to be able to return the following:

```
Name| color| smell
-------------------------
cat | red  | bad
dog | red  | bad 
ant | red  | bad
bee | red  | okay
ape | red  | okay
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY color, smell)  cnt
              FROM animals )
SELECT name, color, smell
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1
```

PS. `color` and `smell` must be NOT NULL.

Answer (score 1):

You can join table with itself to find matching animals and use exists to verify match:

```
SELECT * FROM Animals AS A WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT 1
       FROM Animals AS MatchingAnimal
       WHERE A.color = MatchingAnimal.color
       AND A.smell =  MatchingAnimal.smell
       AND A.Name !=  MatchingAnimal.Name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, not from a performance perspective.

```
create table #temp
(
name varchar(50),
color varchar(50),
smell varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO #temp (Name, color, smell) VALUES ('cat' , 'red'  , 'bad');
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, color, smell) VALUES ('dog' , 'red'  , 'bad');
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, color, smell) VALUES ('rat' , 'red'  , 'good');
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, color, smell) VALUES ('bat' , 'red'  , 'decent');
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, color, smell) VALUES ('bee' , 'red'  , 'okay');
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, color, smell) VALUES ('ape' , 'red'  , 'okay');
INSERT INTO #temp (Name, color, smell) VALUES ('ant' , 'red'  , 'bad');


select t.* from 
#temp t JOIN(SELECT color,smell,count(*) cnt
              FROM #temp
              group by color,smell
              having count(*)>1
              )tt on t.color=tt.color and t.smell = tt.smell
order by t.color,t.smell
```

dbfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd28593183a24c8fc92dff7d22706696)